# Is it possible to export business types and locations in vector format from Google Maps (even for a fee)

Tags: google-maps

I am aware of previous answers but they are a bit old and I would like if solutions exist now. I am looking to get some POI point layer that I can use in QGIS for spatial analysis, to start with for supermarkets and convenience stores. I first used OSM but realized that their data is not that reliable by checking their data against my very own city: one supermarket is called "convenience store", a fruit and vegetable store is called "supermarket"... I then checked Google Maps data and it seems much more reliable. I could pay for this if this service is provided by Google Maps or other providers working with Google at a reasonable price.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way which won't be suitable for big dataset but seems otherwise legit:

https://medium.com/@risky.yanuar/how-to-get-poi-from-google-maps-without-coding-d72564958ac5

You can use My Maps, look for what you are interested in (like "supermarkets near XX"), click the results one by one to place them in a layer and export said layer in csv or kml format, then you can open this in Qgis (I tried with kml).

Of course it won't be practical for big datasets. And I realized that for some reason (human error?) it didn't include a supermarket I know when searching for "supermarkets"). In my case I might just type the names of various supermarket franchises (there are only so many of them in France) and add them to my layer to make sure I include everything I want but without what I don't want.

Comment: "legit" as in "completely against Google map terms of service"? See section [3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services.](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms) of the TOS.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. However I don't intend to scrape this data or use it to create another product, I was only planning to manually save some data from some cities for my own private research, so I guess it's ok (unless you find something specific that prohibits this, in which case I wonder why Google allows us to even export this data as csv or kml).